# How to configure Spring to deserialize JSON into a BigDecimal using a @RequestBody annotation

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, deserialization

My BigDecimals are null when I post to the endpoint "/test".

Payload that I am posting:

```
{
  "decimalOne": "230.0",
  "decimalTwo": "215.0"
}
```

MyObject class:

```
public class MyObject {
    private BigDecimal decimalOne;
    private BigDecimal decimalTwo;

    public MyObject() {
    }

    public MyObject(BigDecimal decimalOne, BigDecimal decimalTwo) {
        this.decimalOne = decimalOne;
        this.decimalTwo = decimalTwo;
    }

    BigDecimal getDecimalOne() {
        return decimalOne;
    }

    BigDecimal getDecimalTwo() {
        return decimalTwo;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class MyObjectController {

    private DecimalService decimalService;

    @Inject
    MyObjectController(DecimalService decimalService){
        this.decimalService = decimalService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Integer getNumberBack(@RequestBody MyObject myObjectPayload){
       return decimalService.getNumber(myObjectPayload);
    }
}
```

How do I get Spring to deserialize the JSON into BigDecimal. Also please let me know if I left out any information. Thanks!

Comment: Add setters to `MyObject`

Comment: I will try that but I am pretty sure that Spring only requires an empty constructor and getters. Adding setters seems like it will eliminate the purpose of encapsulation.

Comment: And that worked. It doesn't make much sense to me because of encapsulation conflict but thanks for that. Can you answer the question and I will accept it? Thanks!

Comment: I think you could also annotate the fields with @JsonProperty (if you don't want to have the setter around).

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Seems a bit tedious having to add @JsonProperty on every variable you want to deserialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add setters to MyObject, because after creation of object using MyObject() deserializer don't have legal way to set fields.